# Executing code in azure example getting error as node already exists

Tags: azure, docker

I am using following link to practice [Docker in azure](https://mikepfeiffer.io/blog/azure-docker-containers)

I created  container registry and created github login
with command prompt and I am able to login to azure

```
docker login mikepff.azurecr.io
```

It signs in successfully but when I am creating clone of github repository, it's giving me error

```
  PS Azure:\> git  clone https://github.com/mikepff/node-docker-demo.git
fatal: destination path 'node-docker-demo' already exists and is not an empty directory.
Azure:/
PS Azure:\>
```

If I do CD docker name, it gives me following error. Can you please tell me where I am going wrong?

```
    cd node-docker-demo
    cd : Cannot find path 'Azure:/node-docker-demo' because it does not exist.
    At line:1 char:1
    + cd node-docker-demo
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Azure:/node-docker-demo:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

Azure:/
PS Azure:\>
```

Comment: Any more questions? Does the solution solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the message that you provide, it seems you use the Azure Cloud Shell. In Azure Cloud Shell, the current path is the home path of the user you use, but you cannot act as you are in that path.

You can see the screenshot in my side:

[image]

It shows the same error as yours. But actually, the directory already exists in the home path of the user your use currently. So you need to check if the directory with the command like this:

```
ls -al
```

**Or** CD the directory in your side like this:

```
cd ~/node-docker-demo/
```